# Oscillation of function and continuity clarification of proof

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

There is a similar question related to this, but it doesn't answer my question, so I would be thankful if anyone helped me with it. There is a step specifically  in the proof I do not understand.

Given $a\in Q$ and $\delta>0$, let $A_\delta$ denote the set of values of $f(x)$ at the points $x$ within $\delta$ of $a$

$$A_\delta={f(x)|x\in Q}, |x-a|<\delta $$

Let $M_\delta=supA_\delta$ and $m_\delta=infA_\delta$. We define the oscillation of the function $f$ at $a$

$$v(f;a)=inf[M_\delta(f)-m_\delta(f)]$$

If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then given $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. It follows that $$M_\delta(f)\le f(a)+\varepsilon$$ and $$m_\delta(f)\ge f(a)-\varepsilon$$

**Here is what I am stuck:**

I dont know how it follows from the previous argument that $v(f;a)\le 2\varepsilon$

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note after fixing $\delta$ and $a$, $M_\delta(f)-m_\delta(f)$ is a nonnegative real number. Hence $$v(f;a)=inf[M_\delta(f)-m_\delta(f)]=M_\delta(f)-m_\delta(f)$$

Then $v(f;a)\le \bigg(f(a)+\varepsilon\bigg)-\bigg(f(a)-\varepsilon\bigg)=2\varepsilon$